# Допустимо ли употреблять обороты "до когда" и "на когда"?

Tags: наречия

Я однажды задавал вопрос о том, как следует спрашивать о времени или дате какого-либо события. Оборот "до когда" посчитали некорректным. Меня интересует, почему. Ведь это субстантивированное наречие. Разве подобные сочетания в этом качестве с предлогом неправильны?

Примеры:

На когда назначен суд?
До когда вы будете заняты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как следует спрашивать о времени или
>   дате какого-либо события.

До какого дня, до какого времени - и проч.

> Оборот "до когда" посчитали некорректным

Правильно посчитали

> Меня интересует, почему.

Потому, что не соответствует норме.

> Ведь это субстантивированное наречие.

Ну знаете, от того, что вы использовали его в этом качестве, нормативным такое употребление не станет.

Узаконенных субстантивированных наречий в русском языке очень мало. Я могу с уверенностью назвать только "завтра" в значении "будущее": "Наше завтра". С меньшим основанием - "вчера" в аналогичном употреблении.

Все остальное - окказиональные варианты. Типа "Из ниоткуда в никуда". Но "когда" даже в этом качестве не употребимо - даже по семантическим причинам, нет у него такого значения.

Answer (score 2):

Оборот "на когда" в разговорной речи встречается достаточно часто.

Грамота.ру вопрос "На когда?" [запрещает](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> Вопрос № 244822:
>
> Здравствуйте! Можно ли так задать вопрос: "На когда запланирована
>   поездка?" Спасибо
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Так сказать нельзя. Правильно: на какой день, на какое число, на какое
>   время запланирована поездка?

В то же время, у классика советской литературы, находим:

[К.М.Симонов "Живые и мертвые. Книга 2. Солдатами не рождаются"](http://www.wysotsky.com/0009/296.htm).

> Сидевшая на скамейке в бюро пропусков Таня увидела входящего
>   Артемьева, встревоженно вскочила.
>
> -- Получайте ваши проездные документы. - Он протянул ей литер и плацкарту.
>
> -- **На когда?**
>
> -- На сегодня, двадцать три тридцать.
>
> -- Большое вам спасибо. И прощайте! - сказала Таня. - Вам, наверное, некогда.

"До когда" - не доводилось слышать.